# Check if file does have different permission than 644 in Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, file-permissions

I have to change permission of a file to 644 if the file does have a different permission than 644.

I have thought of something like this:

```
if [ $(stat -c %A $soubor) ! -eq (-rw-r--r--) ];then...
```

However, it gives errors like:

> integer expression expected

or if I modify it a little, then:

> syntax error):

Comment: What about `if [ $(stat -c %a "$soubour") != '644' ]; then`?

Comment: Why bother checking? Is it really a big deal if the file already has 0644 and you change it to that?

Comment: @das_j thank you! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `[` wrong. It's the same as `test`, so `man test` gives you the manual page to it.
Basically, `[` is a program you call with arguments. For nicer looks, `[` requires the last paramter to be `]`, but there is not technical reason for that.

When you call `[ $a == $b ]`, it fails because `[` will compare `$a` to `=` and complain about the `$b` which it does not expect. So if you want to develop it POSIX-compliant, you need to use `=` instead of `==`.

`-eq` does a numeric compare so `-rw-r--r--` will cause a syntax error because it's not numeric.

`=` will do a string compare, so this is what you need.

You compare with `(-rw-r--r--)` which will be evaulated as command, so you need to add quotes around it (see my comment on your question, I used the octal syntax).

Also, you need to remove the braces so it becomes `'-rw-r--r--'`. I assume you added them because they were on the left side of your if statement.
The reason for the braces on the left is command execution. When you wrap something into `$()`, it will get executed and the output of the command will be filled in there. So after the shell evaluated the expression, it can look like this:

```
'[' '-rw-rw-rw-' '=' '-rw-r--r--' ']'
```

When you use `set -x` anywhere in your shell script, you can see what it acutally does which helps a lot. You can disable it with `set +x` afterwards as it's very verbose.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin `[ is a shell builtin`